# Getting a console message : Failed prop type: The prop `value` is marked as required in `Rating`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, npm

I am getting proptype error due to which I am not able to proper url, on my chrome instead of getting an address i am getting undefined url. like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/order/undefined
```

I place of undefined I should have got some address.

I am not getting where I went wrong.

This is my rating.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Rating = ({ value, text, color}) => {
    return (
        <div className='rating'>
            <span>
                <i style={{color}}
                className={value >= 1 ? 
                'fas fa-star' 
                :
                 value>=0.5 ? 
                'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 
                'far fa-star'}>
                </i>
            </span>
            <span>
            <i style={{color}} 
                className={value >= 2 ? 
                'fas fa-star' 
                :
                 value>=1.5 ? 
                'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 
                'far fa-star'}>
                </i>
            </span>
            <span>
            <i style={{color}} 
                className={value >= 3 ? 
                'fas fa-star' 
                :
                 value>=2.5 ? 
                'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 
                'far fa-star'}>
                </i>
            </span>
            <span>
            <i style={{color}}
                className={value >= 4 ? 
                'fas fa-star' 
                :
                 value>=3.5 ? 
                'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 
                'far fa-star'}>
                </i>
            </span>
             <span>
             <i style={{color}}
                className={value >= 5 ? 
                'fas fa-star' 
                :
                 value>=4.5 ? 
                'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 
                'far fa-star'}>
                </i>
            </span>
            <span>{text && text}</span>
        </div>
    )
}

Rating.defaultProps = {
    color: '#f8e825',
}

Rating.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    color: PropTypes.string,
}
export default Rating
```

And here is my console error message:
[image: And here is my console error message:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check by consoling Value props that you're getting some values or it's coming empty. You marked value props as isRequired, that's why it's showing an error

Comment: So should I write like this: Rating.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.number,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    color: PropTypes.string,
}

Comment: Still getting this url : http://localhost:3000/order/undefined. In place of undifned I should have got order id.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to delete the chunk
}

```js
Rating.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    color: PropTypes.string,
```

I can see you are trying to create a rating component. You don't even have to have the className='Rating' you need to have something like this:

```js
import React from 'react'

const Rating = ({value, text, color}) => {
    return (
        <div>
                            <span>
                    <i style={{color}}
                    className = {
                        value>=1?'fas fa-star':
                        value>=0.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt':
                        'far fa-star'
                    }>

                    </i>
                </span>
                <span>
                <i style={{color}}
                    className = {
                        value>=2? 'fas fa-star':
                        value>=1.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt':
                        'far fa-star'
                    }>

                    </i>
                </span>
                <span>
                <i style={{color}}
                     className = {
                        value>=3? 'fas fa-star':
                        value>=2.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt':
                        'far fa-star'
                    }>

                    </i>
                </span>
                <span>
                <i style={{color}}
                    className = {
                        value>=4? 'fas fa-star':
                        value>=3.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt':
                        'far fa-star'
                    }>

                    </i>
                </span>
                <span>
                <i style={{color}}
                    className = {
                        value>=5? 'fas fa-star':
                        value>=4.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt':
                        'far fa-star'
                    }>

                    </i>
                </span>
                <span>
                    {text && text}
                </span>
        </div>
    )
}
 Rating.defaultProps ={
     color:'#f8e825'
 }
export default Rating
```